# Best way to split an array of strings in ruby?

Tags: arrays, regex, ruby, string, split

If I have an array of strings in ruby and I want to get the resulting array, what is the best way of doing it?

```
array = ["string_apple", "string_banana", "string_orange"]

desired_result = [["string", "apple"], ["string", "banana"], ["string", "orange"]]
```

My current attempt:

`array.map(|r| r.split("_"))`

Comment: @TimurShtatland Added

Comment: Your current attempt is fine except that you should use curly braces for the block in `map`. .  Note that it doesn't change the array.  Maybe you just need to assign it to a variable.  `new_array = array.map { |r| r.split("_") }` or if you want to use the same variable name  `array = array.map {|r| r.split("_") } `

Comment: @SteveTurczyn There is no such syntax in ruby `.map(|r| r.split("_"))`. Language Rust has that syntax.

Comment: Sure there is, except it needs curly braces as I said in my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `map{...}`, not `map(...)` for correct syntax in Ruby here:

```
array = ["string_apple", "string_banana", "string_orange"]

# Assign to a different array:
split_array = array.map{ |s| s.split(/_/) }

# Or modify the original array in place:
array.map!{ |s| s.split(/_/) }

# [["string", "apple"], ["string", "banana"], ["string", "orange"]]
```

Comment: I had to add and exclamation to the map to override the array value .map!

Comment: @SteveG Thank you for the comment! Added `map!` to the answer.